# If not found insert into

Tags: sql, lua

I would like to initate insert into SQL incase SELECT is not found.
This is my code so far

```
res, err, errno, sqlstate =
    db:query("select * from stream_session where username = " .. quoted_user,0)

if not res then
    res1, err, errno, sqlstate =
    db:query("insert into stream_session (username) values (" .. quoted_user .. ")")
end
```

It is checking if user exists but it's not inserting incase user is not found.

Comment: You can set the `username` column to be `UNIQUE` and then simply use `INSERT INTO...`, which will fail if the username already exists.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I had it like that, but im gonna use further select statements, thats why i really do need the SELECT to be there.

Comment: Put a `print(res)` to see what you are getting.

Comment: okey, what i actually found out is `if not res then` only running incase select is not correct syntax or not being able to check in database, so what i need to know is how can i do Select if not found

Comment: I tried `If res:numrows() == 0 then` gave me error.

Comment: Which library are you using to connect to mysql?

Comment: using lua in nginx, library resty.mysql